# F# on List of Elements

Tags: f#

I am trying to write a F# function that finds the biggest value. I am new to F# and am confused as to how to implement this with the correct type and recursion.

Any help would be greatly appreciated along with an explanation of how it works, I really need to understand how it works so I can attempt to create other F# functions. Thanks!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.max%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this recursively, so without the use of Seq.max

Comment: ok, http://stackoverflow.com/a/8463149/240564

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating recursive functions, start thinking about the corner cases. Your helper function takes a list and a "maximum so far". Corner cases: What if your list is empty? What if you only have a 1 element list, or focus on the first element? That directly translates into a `match` statement:

```
let rec helper (l, m) = 
    match l, m with
    | [], m -> m
    | (l1 :: rest), m -> 
        let max1 = if l1 > m then l1 else m
        helper(rest, max1)
```

I'll leave the wrapper `findMax` open, but clearly you can solve that using the same thinking: What if you get an empty list? (scream!) What if you get a list with elements (the first element is your maximum so far, feed the rest of the list into your `helper`)

And of course you could put it all into one function. I've chosen this rather roundabout `helper` because your template code was shaped in that way.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to do is to start *thinking* recursively and/or mathematically. In most general vague terms, it should look like "*The result of my function is...*" - then try to actually put into words what the result should be.

Applying to your particular problem, I would phrase it like this:

- when given a list of one element, the result of `findMax` is that element.
- when given a list of more than one element, the result of `findMax` is the maximum of the lists's head and the maximum element of its tail.

This thinking can be translated into F# almost word for word:

```
let rec findMax list =
   match list with
   | [x] -> x
   | head::tail -> max head (findMax tail)
```

where:

```
let max a b = if a > b then a else b
```

Note, however, that this function is *incomplete*: it doesn't specify what the result should be when given an empty list. I will leave this as an exercise for the reader.